# Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm taking a database class and PHP wasn't really taught.  We were just given code snippets to include in our final project.  The example works, but I cannot get mine to work to save my life.  I decided to strip the form down to one field.  Here's the HTML form snippet:

```
<form method="post" action="add.php">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3">
                <tr>
                  <td>Artist Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="addArtistTextField" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
```

Here's the PHP file (add.php)

```
<?php
//Turn on error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Connects to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("[*****]","[*****]","[*****]","[*****]");

if(!$mysqli || $mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Connection error " . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO mytunes_artists (artist_name) VALUES (?)"))){
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!($stmt->bind_param($_POST['addArtistTextField']))){  // THIS IS LINE 15 GIVING ERROR
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
} else {
    echo "Added " . $stmt->affected_rows . " rows to mytunes_artists.";
}

?>
```

I just want to add an artist name to my table which has 2 fields, artist_id and artist_name.  When I attempt to add the name, I get the following error:

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in
>   /nfs/stak/students/b/brownste/public_html/add.php on line 15 Bind
>   failed: 0 Execute failed: 2031 No data supplied for parameters in
>   prepared statement

What am I doing wrong?  Extremely hard to debug when I don't know PHP.  I've Googled and tried all sorts of things, but nothing works.  It should be noted that my instructor had "ssii" in the bind statement, but when that caused an error for me as well.  No clue what it was for.

Comment: Despite of the fact that debugging is always a hard job, Stack Overflow is a wrong place for asking questions like "please debug my code for me".

Comment: I understand you're new to PHP but the error is really quite clear and simply looking at the documentation would easily solve your issue: [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters)

Comment: Why do people insist on posting these kinds of replies AFTER a question has been answered? Someone was kind enough to help me. Why not just leave it at that? Joe, user1281385 posted the link.  If you read my reply below, you'll see I got it and understood what I was doing wrong.  It's not that I'm "new" to PHP. I'm not taking a PHP class, so debugging is a little difficult. Trust me, I spent hours Googling trying to figure this out on my own because I really hated to ask here knowing I would get responses like this. If you guys don't want to answer my question, then please just move on.

Comment: And for those who can't resist marking my question down for lack of research effort, what exactly does "I have been racking my brain trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here" and "I've Googled and tried all sorts of things, but nothing works" mean? At some point, spinning your wheels becomes a waste of time and common sense dictates you ask for help.  Not answers. just help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says " Wrong parameter count "

so you passing the wrong number of parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

show you need at least 2

try this

```
if(!($stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['addArtistTextField'])))
```

Your instructs ssii means option 1 and 2 are strings 3 and 4 are ints

Comment: ok, great!  that worked.  thanks for the link.  i get it now.  the 's' is just to define what's being passed.  'ssii' didn't work because i was only passing one string and not 4.  thanks!

Comment: From the docs, To bind as a string, other options are i d and b, Check the link for more info